# Run shell and type output

Tags: terminal, mac, iterm, git

I am using iTerm2. I would like to have a keyboard shortcut which runs a command and types the output at the current cursor.

Example: I have a function *branchName* which returns/prints the current folder's branch name. I want the branch name to be written to the shell (iTerm2) by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

Comment: May be this is of some use to you. http://askubuntu.com/questions/525482/how-can-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-the-script-that-i-have-created

Comment: what i want to do is this:
1. start typing: `git push origin`
2. press cmd b 

I am expected to have: `git push origin current-branch-here`

This is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

Open iTerm2 preferences and go to Profiles tab. Select your desired profile and go to Keys tab. Tap plus sign (+) and type the following:

- Keyboard Shortcut: <kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- Action: Send Text
- In the next line add the following command: `git name-rev --name-only HEAD\n`

[image]

After that, when you hit <kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, iTerm send that command to your terminal and will return your current branch.

```
$ git name-rev --name-only HEAD
master
```

Comment: what i want to do is this:
1. start typing: git push origin 
2. press cmd b 
I am expected to have: git push origin current-branch-here

This is just an example.

Comment: i want the action to be run in background and the result to be outputed on the current cursor

Comment: In this case, you can replace the text i suggest in the answer with `$(git name-rev --name-only HEAD)`. That command return your current branch. So, you type `git push origin `, then ⌘cmd+B and  you will have the command to execute: `git push origin $(git name-rev --name-only HEAD)`.